# Make argparse with mandatory and optional arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a argparse system where it takes in 3 arguments, with 1 of them being optional. Depending on the presence of the 3rd argument, the program will decide how to proceed.
I current have this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some description')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--first', help='Filename for f', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--second', help='Filename for s', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-t', '--third', help='Filename for t')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.third:
    parse.classify(args['first'], args['second'], args['third'])
else:
    parse.classify(args['first'], args['second'], None)
```

I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

`Namespace` objects *aren't* subscriptable; they have attributes.

```
parse.classify(args.first, args.second, args.third)
```

You can use `vars` to create a `dict`, though.

```
args = vars(args)
```

Then subscripting will work.

Comment: I did `args = vars(parser.parse_args())`, now I'm getting  `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'mapping'`

Comment: After you reassign `args` to the return value of `vars`, you can't use attribute access anymore. Either use `args.first` with the original return value of `parse_args`, or use `args['first']` with the return value of `vars(args)`.